# I moved Mongo from windows 7 to windows 8 and it refuses to start, even with clean install

Tags: windows, mongodb

I'm trying to setup Mongo on my new laptop and at the start I just copied my Mongo folder on to the new machine. Then I tried with a fresh Mongo download with and without `--dbpath` and I keep getting the same error.

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Mongo documentation doesn't mention this issue or at least I haven't found it.

OLD: Windows 7 Pro 64bit
NEW: Windows 8 Pro 64bit

```
D:\Dropbox\Git\mongodb\bin>mongod.exe --rest --dbpath "D:\Dropbox\Git\mongoDATA"

Sun May 26 16:56:45.565 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=9780 port=27017 d
bpath=D:\Dropbox\Git\mongoDATA 64-bit host=onion
Sun May 26 16:56:45.566 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.1
Sun May 26 16:56:45.566 [initandlisten] git version: 1560959e9ce11a693be8b4d0d16
0d633eee75110
Sun May 26 16:56:45.566 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversio
n(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1') BOOST
_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Sun May 26 16:56:45.566 [initandlisten] allocator: system
Sun May 26 16:56:45.566 [initandlisten] options: { dbpath: "D:\Dropbox\Git\mongo
DATA", rest: true }
Sun May 26 16:56:45.574 [initandlisten] journal dir=D:\Dropbox\Git\mongoDATA\jou
rnal
Sun May 26 16:56:45.574 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no r
ecovery needed
Sun May 26 16:56:45.598 [initandlisten]  course Assertion failure isOk() d:\slav
e\windows_64bit_v2.4.1\mongo\src\mongo\db\pdfile.h 394
Sun May 26 16:56:45.959 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\stacktr
ace.cpp(189)                   mongo::printStackTrace+0x3e
Sun May 26 16:56:45.959 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\assert_
util.cpp(114)                  mongo::verifyFailed+0xdc
Sun May 26 16:56:45.959 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\pdfile.h(
649)                           mongo::DataFileMgr::getExtent+0xcd
Sun May 26 16:56:45.960 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\pdfile.cp
p(852)                         mongo::DataFileMgr::findAll+0x7b
Sun May 26 16:56:45.960 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\database.
cpp(245)                       mongo::Database::clearTmpCollections+0xf3
Sun May 26 16:56:45.960 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\database.
cpp(497)                       mongo::DatabaseHolder::getOrCreate+0x461
Sun May 26 16:56:45.962 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\client.cp
p(317)                         mongo::Client::Context::_finishInit+0xa3
Sun May 26 16:56:45.962 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(33
1)                             mongo::repairDatabasesAndCheckVersion+0x2ce
Sun May 26 16:56:45.962 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(64
9)                             mongo::_initAndListen+0x9fb
Sun May 26 16:56:45.963 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(68
5)                             mongo::initAndListen+0x21
Sun May 26 16:56:45.963 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(12
98)                            mongoDbMain+0x165
Sun May 26 16:56:45.963 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(73
0)                             main+0x9
Sun May 26 16:56:45.965 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self
_64_amd64\crt\src\crt0.c(278)  __tmainCRTStartup+0x13b
Sun May 26 16:56:45.965 [initandlisten] KERNEL32.DLL
                               BaseThreadInitThunk+0x1a
Sun May 26 16:56:45.965 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 0 assertion
d:\slave\windows_64bit_v2.4.1\mongo\src\mongo\db\pdfile.h:394, terminating
Sun May 26 16:56:45.966 dbexit:
Sun May 26 16:56:45.966 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening socke
ts...
Sun May 26 16:56:45.967 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Sun May 26 16:56:45.968 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Sun May 26 16:56:45.968 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...

Sun May 26 16:56:45.968 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Sun May 26 16:56:45.968 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Sun May 26 16:56:45.975 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Sun May 26 16:56:45.975 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Sun May 26 16:56:45.975 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Sun May 26 16:56:45.975 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Sun May 26 16:56:45.976 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Sun May 26 16:56:45.977 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Comment: I've successfully got mongo to use a new database folder but cannot start with the database I had on my w7 machine.

Comment: does it start somewhere other than in your DropBox folder? (Assuming Dropbox is active in that folder given the name)

Comment: It will only start on the w7 machine and has had no trouble with dropbox syncing. I use dropbox as a backup for the mongo db. It seems I have to export my database and then import it on the w8 machine. I would just like to know why this would be.

Comment: was mongod running on your w7 machine when you copied the data directory?

Comment: is this the correct path too? `d:\slav
e\windows_64bit_v2.4.1\mongo\src\mongo\db\pdfile.h`

Comment: @Asya mongo was not running when data was copied

Comment: @naveen I saw that too and have no idea where it's building that path from. No hits on Google returns.

Comment: what's happening is as it's looking through the DB files it's looking for beginning of next extent and it's getting invalid result/address/diskLocation.  Windows 8 is working for other folks so the only thing I can think of is that there is something wrong with the files after the move through Dropbox (though I can't imagine what).

Comment: @Asya I just downloaded my mongo database from dropbox and set up mongodb on a 32bit XP machine. The strange paths also appear in the log. `Tue May 28 10:32:05.083 [initandlisten]   f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src
\crt0.c(278)  __tmainCRTStartup+0x10b` and `c:\10gen\buildslaves\mongo\windows_32bit_v2.4\mongo\src\mongo\db\pdfile.h:394, t
erminating`. The database still works perfectly on the w7 64bit machine. My next step is to use mongo's filesystem snapshots to move the data to w8.

Comment: How about something simpler - just zip up the directory before putting it in Dropbox folder, and then on target machine unzip it into a regular folder.  The strange paths are normal - this is the path to source files in which assertions are happening: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/pdfile.h but it's built on Windows.